# how to find "where" a nested json object without key name

Tags: json, lodash

i have a json object, like this, its a nested json object:

```
{
    "9-10": {
        "users": {
            "9": {
                "userID": 9,
                "name": "Cunlay Zheng",
                "avatarURL": "{\"small\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/small/user9-1492746734\",\"medium\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/medium/user9-1492746734\",\"large\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/large/user9-1492746734\"}",
                "roomID": "9-10",
                "token": "0c4ea3da77d3c98107fd11c0c7c84ad8",
                "socketID": "/moselo#Xa3cWnM4kwQkpijfAAAD"
            },
            "10": {
                "userID": 10,
                "name": "Dominic Vedericho",
                "avatarURL": "{\"small\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/small/user10-1492747647\",\"medium\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/medium/user10-1492747647\",\"large\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/large/user10-1492747647\"}",
                "roomID": "9-10",
                "token": "7f206d64fdfc71af4a783ab47516ef60",
                "socketID": "/moselo#BW8boMD4rA1dhlCzAAAE"
            }
        }
    },
      "11-12": {
        "users": {
            "9": {
                "userID": 11,
                "name": "Cunlay Zheng",
                "avatarURL": "{\"small\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/small/user9-1492746734\",\"medium\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/medium/user9-1492746734\",\"large\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/large/user9-1492746734\"}",
                "roomID": "9-10",
                "token": "0c4ea3da77d3c98107fd11c0c7c84ad8",
                "socketID": "/moselo#Xa3cWnM4kwQkpijfAAAD"
            },
            "10": {
                "userID": 12,
                "name": "Dominic Vedericho",
                "avatarURL": "{\"small\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/small/user10-1492747647\",\"medium\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/medium/user10-1492747647\",\"large\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/large/user10-1492747647\"}",
                "roomID": "9-10",
                "token": "7f206d64fdfc71af4a783ab47516ef60",
                "socketID": "/moselo#BW8boMD4rA1dhlCzAAAE"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

tried to use _filter and _find like bellow without luck

```
 result = _.find(data, function(d) {
     return  d[0] === "9-10"

    //also tried this
    // return d._id === "9-10"

});
```

basically i am trying to find an object with this key "9-10", 
i have google to find some work around, but none work.

need some advice.

Comment: don't you mean `data['9-10']`?

Comment: @njzk2 i have posted my solution, can u suggest which one is better approach?

Comment: if your data really is like you describe it, `data['9-10']` will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

Its an object, so you should NOT use indexes e.g. `0`. You should be able to simply use the key with it, like so -

```
result = d["9-10"]
```

Comment: It will be easier to solve this by looking at more code. Would you be able to share it?

Comment: @HendraLim Works here, so please define "did not work".

Comment: sorry late response, actually i have solved this issue 2 days ago, forgot to post my update.

Comment: @hazardous i also figured that ur solution actually working, 2 days ago i did some mistakes, so ur solution did not working properly, i am voting your answer anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this `result = _.get(data,'9-10')` or `result = _.get(data,'9-10', defaultValue)`.

Just in case you need to get other values:

`users = _.get(data,['9-10','users']);`

`nine = _.get(data,['9-10','users', '9']);`

Pretty sure you get the pattern.

Here's the link to the documentation on _.get: https://lodash.com/docs/#get

Here's a working example:

```js
const data = {
    "9-10": {
        "users": {
            "9": {
                "userID": 9,
                "name": "Cunlay Zheng",
                "avatarURL": "{\"small\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/small/user9-1492746734\",\"medium\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/medium/user9-1492746734\",\"large\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/large/user9-1492746734\"}",
                "roomID": "9-10",
                "token": "0c4ea3da77d3c98107fd11c0c7c84ad8",
                "socketID": "/moselo#Xa3cWnM4kwQkpijfAAAD"
            },
            "10": {
                "userID": 10,
                "name": "Dominic Vedericho",
                "avatarURL": "{\"small\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/small/user10-1492747647\",\"medium\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/medium/user10-1492747647\",\"large\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/large/user10-1492747647\"}",
                "roomID": "9-10",
                "token": "7f206d64fdfc71af4a783ab47516ef60",
                "socketID": "/moselo#BW8boMD4rA1dhlCzAAAE"
            }
        }
    },
      "11-12": {
        "users": {
            "9": {
                "userID": 11,
                "name": "Cunlay Zheng",
                "avatarURL": "{\"small\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/small/user9-1492746734\",\"medium\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/medium/user9-1492746734\",\"large\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/large/user9-1492746734\"}",
                "roomID": "9-10",
                "token": "0c4ea3da77d3c98107fd11c0c7c84ad8",
                "socketID": "/moselo#Xa3cWnM4kwQkpijfAAAD"
            },
            "10": {
                "userID": 12,
                "name": "Dominic Vedericho",
                "avatarURL": "{\"small\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/small/user10-1492747647\",\"medium\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/medium/user10-1492747647\",\"large\":\"http://bs-staging.moselo.com/images/users/large/user10-1492747647\"}",
                "roomID": "9-10",
                "token": "7f206d64fdfc71af4a783ab47516ef60",
                "socketID": "/moselo#BW8boMD4rA1dhlCzAAAE"
            }
        }
    }
}

// Using lodash 4.17.21
const result = _.get(data,'9-10');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this issue, with this approach, i am not sure is this the best way to do it or not, but this solution is working.

```
   var r = _.pickBy(data, function(value, key) {
                    return _.startsWith(key, "9-10");
                });
```

thx for helping.

Comment: Good to know you got it working. If your keys are guaranteed to be unique, I'd recommend not to perform a search for them. A search costs much more than a simple key based lookup.